# Printing datastream from socket

Tags: time-series, mean, modeling, large-data

I am trying to connect to a socket which provides a feed of stock prices (stockID,price), and then print it. The stream is endless. My problem is that I cannot print it.

To begin with, I create a connection:

`con <- socketConnection(host = "88.99.38.191", port = 1337, open = "r")`

then i set a variable reading all the lines.
`data <- readLines(con,-1)`

Then `print(data)`

the problem is that depending on the time gap between executing the connection and setting variable data, the latter receives a different number of values, and that's it.

I am trying to print somehow the entire stream. If I use
`while (TRUE) { print(data) }`

it just prints endlessly the `data` in loops.

Any idea how to implement that?

My ultimate goal is to calculate the moving average for each ID.

Comment: This would probably be better on a programming site like R-help or StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. I have already provided all my code/example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested this is the answer.

```
con <- socketConnection(host = "88.99.38.191", port = 1337, open ="r",blocking = T,server=FALSE)

while(TRUE) {   
data <- readLines(con,1)
print(data)
}
```

The problem with my initial approach was that I didn't use the `blocking = T` property for `socketConnection`. Further info can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html).